# How do I add machine data(SQL Data) into my Visual Studio solution using Azure WebJob?

Tags: sql-server, azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-sql-database, azure-webjobs

I am trying to have access to data on my SQL server however it is another computer/server that at times turns off. Is there a way to use Azure WebJob to add the machine data directly to my visual studio solution. I am new to all of this - sorry if this isn't clear. Any direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Kabooki I think it, you have to directly attach the webjob application from azure into the visual studio.

Here is a tutorial.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs/

and here is how to make it more continues basically asynchronous communication 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-get-started/